# Dynamic select option if radio button checked

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is that I don't know how to combine the 2: radio and select option, I have static radio buttons and dynamic select option from database using php and mysql

```
<label><input type="radio" name="tiptricou" value="1" checked="checked" >1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="tiptricou" value="2">2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="tiptricou" value="3">3</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="tiptricou" value="4">4</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="tiptricou" value="5">5</label>
<label> <input type="radio" name="tiptricou" value="6">6</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="tiptricou" value="7"></label>
```

and the dynamic select option:

```
       `<div id="selecteaza-marimea">
        <?php
        $sql="SELECT marimea FROM stocuri_tricouri where stoc_ramas > 0 order by ID"; 
        echo "<select name='marimea'>"; 
        echo "<option selected disabled>SELECTEAZA MARIMEA</option>"; 
        foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){
        echo "<option value = $row[marimea]> $row[marimea]</option>"; 
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?>
        </div>`
```

mysql database

`id tiptricou marimea cantitate_initiala stoc_ramas
1      1        S            250             250
2      1        M            250             250
3      1        L            250             250
4      2        XL            250             250
5      2        M            250             250
6      3        S            250             250
7      3        M            250             250
8      4        S            250             250
9      5        XL            250             250
10      6        XXL            250             250
11      6        S            250             250
12      7        S            250             250
13      7        M            250             250`

if I check radio 1 should display only 3 data
radio 2 = 2 display select and so on...

now it's show me all data from database at `marimea` column

Comment: have you tried with Ajax ? leave it as it is, but whenever a radio is clicked/checked -> update select via Ajax/PHP

Comment: i'm 0 with ajax, do you have something that i can use it?

Comment: you can check [jQuery Doc -> change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) -> radio is clicked, value is intercepted by jQuery, than Ajax posts to PHP -> php response sent back to `select` (which will be populated by response from DB)

Comment: I recommand that you check the option mentionned in previous comment, then try and write some code, if problem, post another question includng tags `jQuery` + `Ajax` + `PHP`